# Take Photo in Xamarin Android with MvvmCross

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm working on Xamarin Android project and I want to implement taking photo with MvvmCross.

Here's my code:

```
public class PhotoService:IPhotoService
{
    private const int MaxPixelDimension = 1280;
    private const int DefaultJpegQuality = 90;

    private Stream imageStream;

    public Stream ImageStream
    {
        get { return imageStream; }
        set { imageStream = value; }
    }

    public void GetPhoto()
    {
        var task = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxPictureChooserTask>();

        task.TakePicture(
        MaxPixelDimension,
        DefaultJpegQuality,
        SavePicture, null);
    }

    private void SavePicture(Stream stream)
    {
        ImageStream = stream;
    }

}
```

but in:

```
task.TakePicture(
        MaxPixelDimension,
        DefaultJpegQuality,
        SavePicture,
        null);
```

I have error:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

**UPDATE**

in call stack I have:

> 0x0 in Android.Content.Intent..ctor at /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-24/src/generated/Android.Content.Intent.cs:1275,6  C#
>   0x12 in MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser.Droid.MvxPictureChooserTask.TakePicture    C#
>   0x3A in App.Services.PhotoService.PhotoService.GetPhoto at C:\app\App.Services\PhotoService\PhotoService.cs:38,4    C#
>   0x7 in App.ViewModels.ViewModels.MainViewModel.TakePhoto at C:\app\App.ViewModels\ViewModels\MainViewModel.cs:49,4  C#

Comment: Do you have more information? Such as a stack trace. Maybe inner exceptions?

Comment: @Cheesebaron Question updated

Comment: That doesn't seem like the entire stack trace.

Comment: @Cheesebaron how to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative solution you can use Media Plugin that available in nuget
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Media/

You can use dependency service to call the `takePictureAsync` method from android project. With this library you can specify file name and folder path to store your image. This library can also take video using `takeVideoAsync` method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add the MVVMCross.Pugin.PictureChooser package to your Core **and** platform specific projects.

Comment: I have only android project. I added this plugin to Android (core) and my android class library where is PhotoService